# How to accumulate previous values in array of objects in TypeScript

Tags: arrays, typescript

I need to accumulate previous values from an array of objects:

```
"registries": [
    {
      "period_range": "06:00 - 07:00",
      "timestamp": "2021-11-09T09:45:00.000Z",
      "production": {
        "D": 4,
        "P": 3
      },
      "accumulated": {
        "D": 0,
        "P": 0
      },
    },
]
```

Inside the "accumulated" object, I need to get all the previous values of "production", and sum with the current production

Example:

If production D is 5 at 5 a.m, and 3 at 6 a.m, the accumulated at 7 a.m need to be 5 + 3 and + the production of the current period.

Comment: Consider `Array.prototype.reduce` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Comment: What do you want the output to look like?

Answer (score 0):

[`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to get the values, [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to add all the values.

```js
let registries = [
    {
      "period_range": "06:00 - 07:00",
      "timestamp": "2021-11-09T09:45:00.000Z",
      "production": {
        "D": 4,
        "P": 3
      },
      "accumulated": {
        "D": 0,
        "P": 0
      },
    },
];

const reducer = (previousValue, currentValue) => previousValue + currentValue;
const addAllValues = (where) => Object.values(where).reduce(reducer);

let reg = registries[0];
let result = addAllValues(reg.production) + addAllValues(reg.accumulated);

console.log(result);
```